# AddMouseListener into another AddMouseListener

Tags: java, events, mouselistener

I had a problem while calling two mouse events, one into the other. I wanted to show a second frame (frame2) when the user clicks on a component (component1) from the first frame (frame1), then returns to the previous frame (frame1) if the component2 is clicked on. All this using one file. 
This is what I wrote:

```
component1.addMouseListener(this on);

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getSource() == component1)
    {

        frame1.dispose();

        frame2.setVisible(true);

        component2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked() {
            frame2.dispose();

            frame1.setVisible(true);
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

The first event works, but not the second.
Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fully functional example where there are 2 frames, each with a label that, when clicked, hides one frame and shows the other, done in Java 10. See if this works for you and explain how your code differs from this. Note that I only created 2 MouseListeners, one for each frame. I did not recreate the MouseListener in the other MouseListener's code. Also, I did not dispose the frame, which will likely cause problems. If I had disposed frame1, I would most likely have to create a new JFrame and assign it to the frame1 instance member.

Please note you have to click on the label itself, not somewhere else on the frame.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class TwoFrames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TwoFrames twoFrames = new TwoFrames();
        twoFrames.start();
    }

    private void start() {
        setupFrames();
    }

    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Frame 1"),
           frame2 = new JFrame("Frame 2");

    JLabel component1 = new JLabel("Click me 1"),
           component2 = new JLabel("Click me 2");

    private void setupFrames() {
        frame1.getContentPane().add(component1);
        frame2.getContentPane().add(component2);

        component1.setOpaque(true);
        component2.setOpaque(true);

        component1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                frame1.setVisible(false);
                frame2.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        component2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                frame2.setVisible(false);
                frame1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        frame1.setSize(300, 300);
        frame2.setSize(400, 400);

        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> frame1.setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dispose()` method actually destroys the window and so, frame1 should become `null` and you are most likely getting a null pointer exception.

Consider calling `frame1.setVisible(false)` and `frame2.setVisible(false)` instead of the `dispose()` method.

Also, you could consider using to separate mouse listener objects instead of adding a new mouse listener to component2 when component1 is clicked.

Comment: I tried with the setVisible(false) method and it didn't work. I think the problem is in writing another mouse listener withing the first one. Do you have an idea on how to separate them ? The component2 appears only when the frame2 is shown. Otherwise I could have writen the second mouse listener outside the first one.

Comment: See black panda's answer.  It is a fully working example and it uses two mouse listeners.  :)